# Show that T - I is a projection.

Tags: linear-transformations, projection

Came across a question where:

[image: question]

[image: answer for (a) and (b)]

I could solve (a) and (b), but have no clue what (c) means.

Please advice.

Comment: Maybe $I$ is somehere described. before question 7.

Comment: @Narasimham $I$ is clearly meant to be the identity (operator).  It's quite likely that OP does not know what it means for a linear operator to be a projection.

Comment: Not sure why this has so many close votes. Sure the question is not perfect but there is not even advice on how to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)):

> A projection is a linear transformation $P$ from a vector space to itself such that $P^2 = P$.

You have found that 
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
1&1&1\\
1&0&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
 now you have to prove that:
$$
P=(T-I)=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
1&1&1\\
1&0&2
\end{bmatrix}-
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
1&0&1\\
1&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is such that $P^2=P$ (that is easy)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that $$T=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 2\\\end{bmatrix}$$
by looking at the images of $T$ under the canonical basis $\{1,x, x^2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether $(T-I)^2=(T-I)$. If yes,  what are those operators called?

Answer (score 0):

You can show that $(T-I)(a+bx+cx^2)=(a+c)x+(a+c)x^2 \Rightarrow(T-I)^2(a+bx+cx^2)=(T-I)((a+c)x+(a+c)x^2)=(a+c)x+(a+c)x^2\Rightarrow(T-I)^2=(T-I)$